# How can i qualify fields in bcp.exe with quotes

Tags: sql-server

I can specify a comma field seperator in BCP by using the options -c -t ,

How can i enclose the fields in quaotations (")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) or try ["String of up to 10 printable characters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx)